# Global temporary table clears on commit

Tags: plsql, oracle12c, jdbc-odbc

```
CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE "TEMP_TABLE"
   (    
    COLUMNS...

   ) ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS ;
```

I am calling the global temp table from java jdbc innser sql

Global temporary table clears on commit which is not expected

Comment: A global temporary table with `ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS` will clear out the rows when the session is disconnected.  Could you please edit your question to include the code you are using to insert into the temporary table, and the code you are using to query the temporary table?

Comment: Are you sure you're in the same session? The GTT clears if the session is disconnected and you can't see the data with a second session even if the first session is still open.

Comment: As stated, may be you are making a new JDBC connection for the sql call. This link has good info on Global tables https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/temporary-tables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The transaction getting complete and new session is requested on ajax call to load again.

For more details refer below link:
https://oracle-concepts-learning.blogspot.com/2019/07/oracle-gtts.html